# How to copy remote machines text to local machines clipboard through SSH?

Tags: linux, ssh, editing

I work on a remote machine through `ssh`. I have a very large text file there (approx. 500 lines) which I usually need to modify, then copy the contents of that file and paste it in my local browser. The way I usually do this is `cat filename` and then select/copy the ssh output. That takes a lot of time.

I was wondering if there is a utility that will put the remote file's contents in my local clipboard.

Comment: I think you got the title wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Try `ssh` pipes. Here's and example that works with OS X (Mountain Lion) (for Linux, adjust the cli clipboard program accordingly):

From the remote `ssh` machine, run:

```
$ cat /dir/file.txt | ssh user@localMachine pbcopy
```

You can use this functionality in remote vim editors by using ssh certificates
for authorization and adding the following to vimrc on the remote machine:

```
vmap &lt;C-c> y:call system("ssh user@localMachine pbcopy", getreg("\""))
```

<kbd>Control-C</kbd> in the remote editor should now copy to the local clipboard.

Answer (score 2):

If you enable X forwarding then `xclip` can do this.

```
xclip -i -selection clipboard somefile
```

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I'd open the remote file locally through e.g. [Vim's SCP mode](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip337):

```
vim scp://uname@host/myfile
```

then edit and just copy it from Vim (e.g. by `gg"*yG`).

Alternatively you can use [`sshfs`](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html) and the local editor of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

[Far Manager Linux port](https://github.com/elfmz/far2l) supports synchronizing clipboard between local and remote host. You just open local far2l, do "ssh somehost" inside, run remote far2l in that ssh session and get remote far2l working with your local clipboard.

It supportes Linux, *BSD and OS X; I made a [special putty build](https://github.com/unxed/putty4far2l) to utilize this functionality from windows also.